# Maclaurin expansion of a rational function

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I have to find the Maclaurin expansion of
$$g(x)=\frac{x^{2}}{x^{6}+2x^{3}+1}$$
I know
$$x^{6}+2x^{3}+1=(1+x^{3})^{2}$$
then
$$g(x)=\left(\frac{x}{1+x^{3}}\right)^{2}$$
But I have no idea how to find it. I tried partial fractions, but it seemed it'd make harder to do.

Comment: What about if you use that your function is the derivative of the geometric series $\frac{1}{1+x^3}$ up to a $-1/3$ factor and just differentiate term by term the geometric series?

Comment: You can also write it as $x^2(1+x^3)^{-2}$ and use the binomial expansion: $(1+y)^{\alpha}=1+\alpha y+\alpha(\alpha-1)y^2/2!+\dots$ with $y=x^3$.

Comment: @Conrad thank you so much! Any idea how do I find the 2017th derivate of $g$ at $x=0$?

Comment: The maclaurin series of $g$ has non zero coefficients only at powers that are 3$k$+2, so 2,5,8, ...2015, 2018, so only the derivatives of those orders are non-zero at 0, hence the 2017th derivative is 0 at x=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments
$$g(x)=\left(\frac{x}{1+x^{3}}\right)^{2}=-\frac 13 \left(\frac{1}{1+x^{3}}\right)'$$ For the time being, let $y=x^3$ and remember that
$$\frac{1}{1+y}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n y^n\implies \frac{1}{1+x^{3}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{3n}$$ Then
$$g(x)=-\frac 13\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{3n} \right)'=-\frac 13\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n 3n \,x^{3n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} n\, x^{3n-1}$$